# Cloudbuild service account doesn't have access to projectID

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to automate building android application apks following in that quest this link: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/building-android-apk-with-cloud-build-gradle-docker-image?fbclid=IwAR1z_1U0MHHqKJ57EeN__bLRDdq1kMQmK068gYmlt23mBtRfFoITg9qCKuM

I did everything in the link, granted all possible permissions to the cloudbuild service accound but each time I make a new push to the repository it fails generating new apk with the following error:

```
generic::failed_precondition: cloudbuild service account doesn't have access to projectID "lustrous-bit-271019"
```

I couldn't find anyone mentioning this anywhere which means it's stupid mistake because I am newbie, thanks in advance.

Comment: What roles does your service account have? According to the guide, you're needing the default Editor role + Storage Object Admin. Looking at the error, the issue seems to lie in IAM permissions, troubleshooting should start from there.

Comment: What's your current project? the same as mentioned in the error?

Comment: Cloud Build Service Account permission was missing

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I needed to add the role:

```
Cloud Build Service Account
```

to the account:

```
[PROJECT_ID]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
```